# move_uploaded_file() Unable to move error... when all else fails

Tags: php, file-upload

I've been put through the ringer with move_uploaded_file() giving me 'Unable to move' error.  So I've checked and

- directory permissions are good
- I have tried using absolute and relative paths
- I checked my php.ini settings
- I checked the tmp_name exists and is uploaded to /tmp directory

The file is actually appearing in the directory I want it to, but is 0 bytes.  I used these exact scripts and settings on another account on the server and they worked fine.  Anything else I can try to debug this issue?  Many thanks

Comment: You need to make sure the stream is closed. However you are uploading the file, it looks like the process still has the file locked.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it may not be an answer that a lot of people have to deal with but here is what fixed it for me.  My disk quota for this user was exceeded, and I increased the disk quota under WHM and it works again.  Hope it helps someone else out there.